# how does spacy generate word vector even that is not a word?

Tags: vector, nlp, load, spacy

Plz take a look at my code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
a=nlp('fjoeij foeijfo foejf')
a[0].vector
array([ 4.4017673 ,  2.2732968 ,  1.8201342 ,  0.285315  ,  4.301816  ,
       -1.6101733 , -1.9763635 ,  0.7946968 , -0.49857655,  2.4312825 ,
       -0.5321884 ,  1.8810408 , -2.4434211 , -0.1565853 , -0.3007983 ,
       -0.5251692 , -0.47107434,  2.392819  , -2.1653428 ......
```

You can see that they are not words, I just randomly typed in. But spacy can still generate the vectors. So, I have two questions:

1. How spacy generate vectors?
2. All the vectors are 96 dimensions. Can I change the number of dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sm` models don't have static word vectors, so `token.vector` returns context-sensitive tensors from the tok2vec model as a backoff. The dimensions setting comes from the tok2vec model parameters and can't be changed after the model is initialized and trained.

These tensors are useful for the tagger/parser/etc. components in the pipeline, but probably aren't that useful otherwise, e.g. for similarity comparisons, where you'd be better off using a `md` or `lg` model with static word vectors.

See: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity